# How to resolve "dns record for '' under zone Document is already taken." in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am learning to create DB account, DB, and container inside the DB in `CosmosDB` via `ARM template`.

If I follow this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/quick-create-template?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-resource-manager%2Ftemplates%2Ftoc.json&tabs=PowerShell, then I can successfully create all these. I have also confirmed that when I run this second time, it would simply create another container only (not DB account and DB, which is great).

Now the problem is, when I want to just create a container in an existing account, I see `Dns record for c4p-dev under zone Document is already taken. Please use a different name for the account.` error and not sure why.

i.e., this works. It doesn't throw error if DB account and DB exists, simply creates the new container (when I defined it)

```
  "accountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('sql-{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Cosmos DB account name, max length 44 characters"
      }
    }
```

if I use this, then it throws error:

```
"accountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().id]", // OR if I hard code this with "c4p-dev"
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Cosmos DB account name, max length 44 characters"
      }
    }
```

**Questions:**

- Shouldn't this behave the same way the other one behaves?
- Is this happening because I have the same resource and account name?
  i.e., `c4p-dev`

**Additional Info:**

- Resource group: c4p-dev
- Cosmos DB Account name: sql-43n3q7hq3aufo (this is created from first example). I also have c4p-dev account which was already created and I want to create containers over there.

**CLI Command:**

```
templateFile="/ARM_Template/azurecosmosdeploy.json"
az deployment group create \
  --name adddatabasecontainer2 \
  --resource-group c4p-dev \
  --template-file $templateFile
```

**azurecosmosdeploy.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
   "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.5.6.12127",
      "templateHash": "5817349859578875069"
    }
   },
   "parameters": {
    "resourceTags": {
      "type": "object",
      "defaultValue": {
        "Environment": "Dev",
        "BillTo": "specialprojects",
        "Architecture": "AppService",
        "AlertName": "mgmt"
      }
    },
    "accountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().id]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Cosmos DB account name, max length 44 characters"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for the Cosmos DB account."
      }
    },
    "primaryRegion": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The primary replica region for the Cosmos DB account."
      }
    },
    "secondaryRegion": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The secondary replica region for the Cosmos DB account."
      }
    },
    "defaultConsistencyLevel": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Session",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The default consistency level of the Cosmos DB account."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Eventual",
        "ConsistentPrefix",
        "Session",
        "BoundedStaleness",
        "Strong"
      ]
    },
    "maxStalenessPrefix": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 100000,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Max stale requests. Required for BoundedStaleness. Valid ranges, Single Region: 10 to 1000000. Multi Region: 100000 to 1000000."
      },
      "maxValue": 2147483647,
      "minValue": 10
    },
    "maxIntervalInSeconds": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 300,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Max lag time (minutes). Required for BoundedStaleness. Valid ranges, Single Region: 5 to 84600. Multi Region: 300 to 86400."
      },
      "maxValue": 86400,
      "minValue": 5
    },
    "automaticFailover": {
      "type": "bool",
      "defaultValue": true,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Enable automatic failover for regions"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        true,
        false
      ]
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "c4p",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name for the database"
      }
    },
    "containerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "ARMTemplateSample2",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name for the container"
      }
    },
    "throughput": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 400,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The throughput for the container"
      },
      "maxValue": 1000000,
      "minValue": 400
    }
   },
   "variables":{
    "consistencyPolicy": {
      "Eventual": {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Eventual"
      },
      "ConsistentPrefix": {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "ConsistentPrefix"
      },
      "Session": {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Session"
      },
      "BoundedStaleness": {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "BoundedStaleness",
        "maxStalenessPrefix": "[parameters('maxStalenessPrefix')]",
        "maxIntervalInSeconds": "[parameters('maxIntervalInSeconds')]"
      },
      "Strong": {
        "defaultConsistencyLevel": "Strong"
      }
    },
    "locations": [
      {
        "locationName": "[parameters('primaryRegion')]",
        "failoverPriority": 0,
        "isZoneRedundant": false
      },
      {
        "locationName": "[parameters('secondaryRegion')]",
        "failoverPriority": 1,
        "isZoneRedundant": false
      }
    ]
   },
   "resources":[
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-10-15",
      "name": "[toLower(parameters('accountName'))]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
      "properties": {
        "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('consistencyPolicy')[parameters('defaultConsistencyLevel')]]",
        "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
        "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
        "enableAutomaticFailover": "[parameters('automaticFailover')]"
      },
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases",
      "apiVersion": "2021-10-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', toLower(parameters('accountName')), parameters('databaseName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "[parameters('databaseName')]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts',toLower(parameters('accountName')))]"
      ],
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-10-15",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', format('{0}/{1}', toLower(parameters('accountName')), parameters('databaseName')), parameters('containerName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "[parameters('containerName')]",
          "partitionKey": {
            "paths": [
              "/testPartitionKey"
            ],
            "kind": "Hash"
          },
          "indexingPolicy": {
            "indexingMode": "consistent",
            "includedPaths": [
              {
                "path": "/"
              }
            ],
            "compositeIndexes": [
              [
                {
                  "path": "/name",
                  "order": "ascending"
                },
                {
                  "path": "/age",
                  "order": "descending"
                }
              ]
            ]
          },
          "uniqueKeyPolicy": {
            "uniqueKeys": [
              {
                "paths": [
                  "/phoneNumber"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "options": {
          "throughput": "[parameters('throughput')]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases', split(format('{0}/{1}', toLower(parameters('accountName')), parameters('databaseName')), '/')[0], split(format('{0}/{1}', toLower(parameters('accountName')), parameters('databaseName')), '/')[1])]"
      ],
      "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]"
    }
   ]
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if the cosmos account name and the resource group are the same. But account names in Cosmos DB need to be globally unique so if you're trying to deploy an ARM template in a different resource group but the same cosmos account name then you're going to get an error.

Comment: @MarkBrown It is in same resource group. What I did is, first created a template to make sure it works where I am creating an DB account and container in it. This is from scratch, so I can do this N times without any issue.
I think the issue is, the account name `c4p-dev` was created earlier, and I am trying to create a container in it where I see the issue. If I give `c4p-dev2`, etc. name, It is working as expected. I have to check what happens if I delete that manually and then re-create it via template.

Comment: If you're trying to create a new container in the same account, then you need to just add the json for the new container, keeping the other items the same in the ARM template.

Comment: On my side it's probably a bug from Azure: I suspect the previous cosmos DNS partially deleted